# How to incremental search using TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I am learning `TVirtualStringTree` usage and must implement an incremental search. When the user enters characters into a `TEdit` I want to move the focused node to the first qualifying node in the tree.

I'm reading through all the demo and example code I can find and cannot seem to find a starting place for this. Can anyone get me started with pseudo code or better?

Comment: Your question is confusing, when you say `and not must implement an incremental search` do you mean that you have to use incremental searching or not?

Comment: @PeterVonča "not" should be "I".

Answer (score 6):

The control supports incremental searching already. You don't need to add any edit control; just start typing into the tree control, and it will select the next matching node. Set the `IncrementalSearch`, `IncrementalSearchDirection`, `IncrementalSearchStart`, and `IncrementalSearchTimeout` properties as needed.

To select the first node that matches given criteria, use `IterateSubtree`. Write a method matching the signature of `TVTGetNodeProc` to check a single node against your search criteria. It will be called for each node in the tree, and if the node matches, then it should set the `Abort` parameter to true. Use the third parameter of `IterateSubtree` (named `Data`) to communicate the search term to your callback function along with any other search criteria.

Answer (score 4):

I've stripped some of the unnecessary code, but here you go:

```
unit fMyForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Forms, StdCtrls, VirtualTrees, StrUtils;

type
  TfrmMyForm = class(TForm)
    vstMyTree: TVirtualstringTree;
    myEdit: TEdit;
    procedure myEditChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SearchForText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Data: Pointer; var Abort: Boolean);
  end;

  PDatastructure = ^TDatastructure;
  TDatastructure = record
    YourFieldHere : Widestring;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMyForm.SearchForText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Data: Pointer; var Abort: Boolean);
var
  NodeData: PDatastructure; //replace by your record structure
begin
  NodeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  Abort := AnsiStartsStr(string(data), NodeData.YourFieldHere); //abort the search if a node with the text is found.
end;

procedure TfrmMyForm.myEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  foundNode : PVirtualNode;
begin
  inherited;
  //first param is your starting point. nil starts at top of tree. if you want to implement findnext
  //functionality you will need to supply the previous found node to continue from that point.
  //be sure to set the IncrementalSearchTimeout to allow users to type a few characters before starting a search.
  foundNode := vstMyTree.IterateSubtree(nil, SearchForText, pointer(myEdit.text));

  if Assigned (foundNode) then
  begin
    vstMyTree.FocusedNode := foundNode;
    vstMyTree.Selected[foundNode] := True;
  end;
end;

end.
```